# There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script: ReferenceError: randomNo is not defined

Tags: postman

I am getting this error message while trying to run postman script. I am not sure how to fix the randomNo not defined error. Can someone help me on this with the query with easy explanation.

"There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script: ReferenceError: randomNo is not defined"

Somehow i referred in google and defined this query for randomNo,

```
   const getRandomNo = (min, max) => {
   min = Math.ceil(min);
   max = Math.floor(max);return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;}`
```

The purpose of randomNo here is, there is a field name "serviceBillName" given in the request body, example format (Test01User = Test+01+User),

So I am tried to get the generated RandomNo for below variable

`var serviceBillName = "Test"+**getRandomNo(1,200)**+"User";`

to set global variable for the for the field name "serviceBillName" in the request body as **{{serviceBillName}}**
`pm.globals.set("serviceBillName", serviceBillName`);

Comment: check for scope of getRandomNo. Is it accessible where you are using? Add the class and where you are calling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how / why you're using this to create random numbers but Postman has that built it.

This can be either through `{{$randomInt}}` - Which will give you a number between 0 > 1000

Or with Lodash, by using the `_.random(min, max)` function.

*Edit*

```
var serviceBillName = `Test${_.random(1,200)}User`; 
pm.globals.set("serviceBillName", serviceBillName);
```

Comment: Thanks Danny for your reply.

Comment: I am trying to get the generated RandomNo in below variable (getRandomNo (1,200)) and with that tried to set a global variable as {{serviceBillName}} in request body to generate different serviceBillNames in (Test+01+User) format. Not sure this is the correct way of doing.

Comment: 'var serviceBillName = "Test"+getRandomNo(1,200)+"User";
pm.globals.set("serviceBillName", serviceBillName);'